# object detection script error a Winerror 2 a not specefied subprocess and numpy not being recognised?

Tags: python, numpy, subprocess, python-3.7

I run the object detection script and I got the Win error 2 from subprocess. I use Python 3 and there was another error about a ttf file that I fixed. The only thing is remained was the subprocess problem.

Here is the error:

```py
     File "F:\grade pro\mid left fork yolo v3\real-time-audio.py", line 127, in <module>
        tts = AudioSegment.from_mp3("tts.mp3")
      File "F:\grade pro\python3\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 716, in from_mp3
        return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
      File "F:\grade pro\python3\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 697, in from_file
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "F:\grade pro\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "F:\grade pro\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Every time I run my program in Python 3 I get this error. When I run it in Python 2 I get numpy `Not specified` error.

Comment: Please share your code. In addition- regarding numpy- probably you have installed it only on python 3, if you want to use it with python 2- install in there too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572582/winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-python)